# Is it true that if $a\equiv b \pmod m$ then $am\equiv bm \pmod{m^2}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Just what the title says, I have searched but haven't found anything, either for yes or no.
Does somebody know?

My reasoning is:

$a \equiv b \pmod m$

$\implies a = b + mk$, for some $k$

$\implies$ multiply both sides by $m$ and I get $am = (b + mk)m$

$\implies am  = bm + (m^2)k$

$\implies am \equiv bm \pmod {m^2}$

Is that right? Am I missing something?

Comment: This follows directly from the definition:  $a \equiv b \bmod m$ if and only if $a-b = mx$ for some integer $x$.  This is equivalent to your argument, which is fine.

Comment: Indeed, $a\equiv b\bmod m\iff an\equiv bn\bmod mn$.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.  It's best for site health to delete this dupe question (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)